# Collatz conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251907/a-very-different-property-of-numbers-can-be-changed-to-1-by-applying-only-the)

After seeing this question, I observed first 10 natural numbers , I saw this

> For every $n\in \mathbb N$ and $n\ne 2^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ , after applying these two operations , these terms must occurs,
>   $$10,5,16,8,4,2$$
>   Only thing I want is a counter example or a satisfoctary answer about the truth of this fact

Note that in case of $5, 10$ will be ommitted from the list , but it follows for every other $n$

I am still checking for more numbers to found a counter example myself

But since I am doing it with a copy pen, I can never reach a conclusion

Please help!!!

Comment: @Arnaud.D I want a counter example if this is false or an explanation why this is true

Comment: Not sure why this got two downvotes - it's a reasonable question to ask, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from $21$ gives you
$$21,64,32,16,8,4,2,1.$$
Starting from $85$ gives you
$$85,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,1.$$
In general, every power of $4$ is of the form $3m+1$, with $m$ necessarily odd; so you can always find odd numbers that get mapped to a power of $4$, and thus the induced sequence does not pass contain $10$ nor $5$.

Comment: +1. For the OP, a proof of the statement that every power of $4$ is of the form $3m+1$ with $m$ odd: to see that every power of $4$ is of the form $3m+1$, note that $4$ itself is, and $(3m+1)(3n+1)=9mn+3n+3m+1=3(3mn+m+n)+1$ is of the form $3k+1$ (more concisely: $4=1 (mod 3)$, so $4^k=1^k(mod 3)=1(mod 3)$). And if $m$ is even, then $3m+1$ is odd, so if $4^k=3m+1$ then $m$ must be odd.